# Reducing a list of beans using streams in Java 8

Tags: java, java-stream

Imagine you have an array list of beans, with several properties:

```
class Item {
    public int id;
    public String type;
    public String prop1;
    public String prop2;
    public String prop3;
}
```

And you have a List with the following values:

```
id | type| prop1| prop2| prop3
1  | A   | D    | E    | F
1  | B   | D    | E    | F
2  | A   | G    | H    | I
2  | B   | G    | H    | I
2  | C   | G    | H    | I
```

I want to reduce this to a List containing:

```
id | type    | prop1| prop2| prop3  
1  | A, B    | D    | E    | F
2  | A, B, C | G    | H    | I
```

Notice, for the same id, the instance properties have exactly the same values except for the type.

Is there a way to do it using streams?

Comment: just to clarify, the type, will be a concatenation of the types with the same id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, group the collection by `Item::getId` and save the result to a `Map<Integer, List<String>>`. Second, turn each entry into an item and collect them in a resulting list.

```
List<Item> result = list
    .stream()
    // build a Map<Integer, List<String>>
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Item::getId, Collectors.mapping(Item::getType, Collectors.toList())))
    .entrySet()
    .stream()
    // transform an entry to an item
    .map(i -> new Item(i.getKey(), String.join(", ", i.getValue().toArray(new String[0]))))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

To clear up the stream chain, you can move the construction logic in a separate method and use a reference to that method (like `map(Item::fromEntry)`:

```
public static Item fromEntry(Map.Entry<Integer, List<String>> entry) {
    return new Item(
        entry.getKey(),
        String.join(", ", entry.getValue().toArray(new String[0]))
    );
}
```

Comment: Hi. Very nice solution, only one problem. The Item has more fields, that are the same value for the same Id, except for the type. So, I want to reduce that, the items that are equal except for the type, and the type, to be that concatenation:

id | type | field1 | field2 | field3 
1  | A     | AA     | AAA   | AAAA 
1  | B     | AA     | AAA   | AAAA 
2  | A     | BB     | BBB   | BBBB 
2  | B     | BB     | BBB   | BBBB 
2  | C     | BB     | BBB   | BBBB

Comment: Hi. Very nice solution, only one problem. The Item class has more fields, that are the same value for the same Id, except for the type. So, I want to reduce that, the items that are equal except for the type, and the type, to be that concatenation.

Comment: Please edit your question by adding what you have tried so we can reopen it. I will edit the answer a bit later